# Eclipse create empty node.js express project

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I start to learn node.js with express. The tutorial say to install nodeclipse plugin for Eclipse IDE and then create a new Express project.

according to the tutorial, you should have a new project with all 'inside the basic structure to start.

When i create new express project it empty, there arn't any file.

I have follow the procedure of tutorial, I can not figure out where mistake

Comment: when i run 'express -h' nothing append.i try to remove express and node and reinstall.

Comment: Correct name is Nodeclipse http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something went wrong with your installation.

You could try to re-install nodeclipse:

1. Go to http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/
2. Download Enide Studio with all nodeclipse plugins for your OS under 4). Now creating an Express project should already work (worked for me, Windows 8, 64bit)
3. On the same page, follow the instructions under B) to update the plugins

Comment: I have this error on console. '/usr/sbin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/bin/express /tmp/express-work/1396298696475/primo 
Unexpected Exception'

Comment: Good that the re-install worked for you. 'Unexpected Exception' is of course not very helpful when trying to find out what went wrong ;-)

Comment: Just tried this with Windows 7, 64 bit install and still gives same error.

Answer (score 1):

Usage page http://www.nodeclipse.org/usage has steps:

### Generating of Express project

1. Select File -> New -> Node Express Project.
2. Enter [Project name], select preferred Template Engine, and press [Finish] button.
3. Wait for npm to finish dowloading dependencies. Press F5(refresh) for node_modules folder to appear.

Also from command line (check `express -h` for options),
then `nodeclipse -g` to prepare to import into Eclipse/Enide Studio

Comment: The error occurs as soon as the express project is created